# ParallelCollectionScan only returns 1 cursor no matter what parameter is passed to numCursors

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, parallel-processing, database, nosql

```
db version v3.2.8

build environment:

distmod: ubuntu1404
distarch: x86_64
target_arch: x86_64
```

I'm trying to use parallelCollectionScan on a collection with about 150M records. It seems that no matter what parameter I pass to numCursors, I only ever get one cursor back...

Any ideas?

Mongo is living in a single node so parallelCollectionScan should work...
If anyone knows of any NoSQL database that allows for "easy to use" parallel extraction of records...please let me know

Comment: What MongoDB storage engine and driver version are you using? If you are using WiredTiger this outcome is expected (pending resolution of https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17688). If you are using MMAPv1 can you include your `db.collection.stats()`?